# Application.AutoCorrect.AutoExpandListRange = False only for columns in VBA?

Tags: excel, vba

Is it possible to turn off automatic table expansion only for columns in vba?
I have a table in which the user should be able to add new lines, and I want the table to expand automatically for these, but I do not want the user to expand the table by adding new columns. (They still can do calculations in the columns after the table, but it should not expand for these calculations.)
I only know the AutoExpandListRange property for this, but is it possible to make it False only for columns?

```vb
Application.AutoCorrect.AutoExpandListRange = False
```

Comment: I am not aware of a direct way to do this. You can however control that using `.ListObjects("Table Name").Resize` in the `Worksheet_Change` event